# Makefile rule dependencies defined in several lines

Tags: makefile

Are these two formulations equivalent in Makefile, in terms of order of evaluation?

```
rule: dep1
rule: dep2
```

and

```
rule: dep1 dep2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "order of evaluation", but in both cases make will try to build first `dep1` and then `dep2`, guaranteed.  In a parallel build situation they might be both run at the same time, but `dep1` will always be started first.

I should say that if your makefile was more complicated there are other things that could change the order.  For example, prerequisites in an explicit or implicit rule are always tried first.

Also, if the prerequisites of `dep1` and `dep2` took different amounts of time and you were running in parallel, `dep2` might be started before `dep1`.

Comment: Right, so my motivation is incorrect, but still, I believe it might be interesting to know if both forms are equivalent, so that I can always choose which one to use to improve readability of the Makefile.

Comment: Well, I said in the first sentence above that they were.

Comment: Thanks, I thought you meant that only related to the dependencies themselves, not other aspects.
I suppose this is also valid even if there are other rules defined between two occurrences of the same rule?

Comment: I'm not sure what other aspects you mean, since the only thing being specified in the above makefile are dependencies.  But, they result in the same internal structure.  Even if there are other rules defined in between.  You can use the `-p` flag to print make's internal database and see... internally make doesn't even store the fact that they were on two different lines originally.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I believe putting this information directly in your answer would be useful so that others would not need to read the comments.